# Is the viral PostgreSQL array slicing behavior standard?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I was reading the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), and noticed that array slicing is kind of "**viral**" across dimensions:

> If any dimension is written as a slice, i.e., contains a colon, then
>   all dimensions are treated as slices.

For example the `[2]` in

```
SELECT schedule[1:2][2] FROM sal_emp;
```

does not mean the second element, but rather  means [1:2], so that the above is equivalent to:

```
SELECT schedule[1:2][1:2] FROM sal_emp;
```

This is rather confusing. The documentation does not say, and I was wondering if this behavior is defined in SQL standards or is it a postgres feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While one dimensional arrays and the notation `column_name[1]` are part of the SQL standard the ability to extract slices is non-standard.

There are actually only very few databases that support arrays at all.

To my knowledge these are (apart from Postgres) [Firebird](http://firebirdsql.org/), [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) and [H2 Database](http://h2database.com/). But none of these offer array slicing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a Postgres feature, because [neither MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) nor [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) even support an array column type to slice.